# Assign a View to a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-view

I want to draw a path that is confined to just a single `RelativeLayout`, not the entire layout. So I have my DrawPath Class like this:

```
public class DrawPath extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
Path path = new Path();
...
```

And then in my Main Activity I have this bit of code:

```
RelativeLayout gB_RL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel_RL);

dp = new DrawPath(this);
dp.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
// setContentView(dp);
```

I've commented out `setContentView(dp);` because that would assign the DrawPath class to the entire layout. But what I can't figure out is how to assign DrawPath to just the `gB_RL` Relative Layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `ViewGroup` subclasses (such as `RelativeLayout`) have a collection of [`addView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)) methods that you can use to add a new View to that ViewGroup.

In this case, your call can be as simple as `gB_RL.addView(dp)`.

Since you are using a RelativeLayout, you probably want to also create an instance of [`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) and set that on your `dp` View so that you can align the `dp` View correctly.